# Encapsulating builders in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

I have 2 builders in my codebase, which can be accessed like this :

```
return new Developer.Builder("John", "Doe").age(30).build();
return new Manager.Builder("Eve", "Page").age(40).build();
```

I want to make the API simpler by encapsulating in an enum :

```
return Google.Developer.Builder("John", "Doe").age(30).build();
return Google.Manager.Builder("Eve", "Page").age(40).build();
```

My goal is to simplify the process for

1. Changing company names from Google to Microsoft
2. If a new role is added (apart from Developer and Manager), users of my code can know about it in one place.

Only option which comes to my mind is having company name as enum - but then I won't be able to implement builder pattern.

Comment: Why not have an `Employee` class provide these builders so that `Role` and `Company` could be enums of their own (and you would add corresponding builder methods to `Employee`)?

Comment: There is not an unchanging list of companies; `enum` might not be the best way to represent them.

Comment: Whether a company should or could be modeled as an enum depends entirely on the application -- we don't have enough information.

Comment: @AndyTurner : Can you please explain a potential problem with an enum that changes. Almost all enums I have been using are prone to change in future.

Comment: @MickMnemonic : I am evaluating your option. Let me get back in a while.

Comment: @AndyTurner : Here is an example from Android SDK : http://bit.ly/1KESRjr. CompressFormat has changed over time to support new formats.

Comment: @SlowAndSteady it's not so much that changing is a problem, it's that companies don't have the same release cycle as your software. It's much easier to handle new companies if they can be created when required, rather than requiring a new build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an API similar to what you describe:

```
enum Google {
    Developer, Manager;

    public Builder builder(String name) {
        return new Builder(this, name);
    }

    public static class Builder {
        public Builder(Google role, String name) { ... }
        public Builder age(int age) { ... }
        public Employee build() { ... }
    }
}
```

Now you can write

```
Employee e = Google.Developer.builder("John").age(30).build();
```

I don't see what the point is for all this. Do the builders somehow depend on the company and role in a non-trivial way?

If not, you can define the Builder as a separate class and use an interface to mark what ever represents roles in companies, similar to Sleiman's answer. 
You could even parametrize the `Employee` class with company, if this makes sense in your application...

```
interface CompanyRole { /* just a marker */ }

enum Google implements CompanyRole { 
    ...
    Employee.Builder<Google> builder(String name) {
        return new Employee.Builder<>(this, name);
    }
}

class Employee<T extends CompanyRole> { 
    ... 

    static class Builder<T extends CompanyRole> {
        EmployeeBuilder(T role, String name) { ... }
        Employee<T> build() { ... }
    }
}
```

And you can still write

```
Employee<Google> e = Google.Developer.builder("John").age(30).build();
```

Comment: Not as of now, but I just want to take care of future dependencies. I guess this approach will work for me after some changes. Once tested, I will accept this answer.

Comment: I agree with Joni.  I do not see why the builder would be declared in something like `Google` as opposed to `Employee`.  I would expect something like `Employee guy = Employee.getBuilder().setName("John", "Smith").setRole(Role.MANAGER).setCompany(Company.GOOGLE).setAge(45).build();` instead.  I think this makes it easier to subclass the idea of an employee for polymorphic behavior later.  It allows you to turn the roles and companies into strategies later if necessary.

Comment: In contrast, putting the `Builder` outside of the `Employee` class necessitates that either the `Employee` is a bean or they need package access to each other.  Either way, you run the risk of creating a situation where an `Employee`'s data state is not trustworthy after the constructor call.  In my mind, the whole point of a builder is to ensure that the built object's constructor is not called by anyone but the builder and that its post-constructor state is trustworthy.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an interface that represents a company

```
interface Company{
}
```

And have an enum of well known companies,

```
enum Companies implements Company{
 GOOGLE,
 MICROSOFT,
 ...
}
```

And now in your builder you can add a method that takes a `Company` rather an `enum`

```
Builder company(Company company){
  addCompany(company);
  return this;
}
```

And construct it fluently like this

```
Developer.Builder("John", "Doe").company(Companies.GOOGLE).age(30).build();
```

And now companies can either be constants or something you load from a db (anything that implements `Company`). It is type-safe either ways.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that not all companies have the same roles. So I would need to throw exceptions in the company() method. A solution like Google.Developer.Builder() makes it easier for the clients.

Answer (score 1):

### Review

```
return Google.Developer.DevBuilder("John", "Doe").age(30).build();
```

This makes no sense. Taking a closer look, above call leads to a class `Google`, which contains an inner class `Developer`. That class defines a **static method** called `DevBuilder` that takes 2 parameters, first and last name, and returns an instance of `Builder`/`DeveloperBuilder`.

This is not an object oriented, extensible approach. Even though you gave us very little context, I'd argue that companies are static objects, which are not subject to change. Referring to the example you made in the comments - a new company is more likely than a new `CompressFormat`.

Further, there is no possibility to change behaviour via polymorphism, except for the dynamic calls to `age(int)` and `build()`.

### Dynamic approach

Below a concept of a more dynamic approach (of course mechanics should be added, to make sure that there is only one object for a company, e.g. `Company.byName("Google")` etc.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Company google = new Google();
    Manager manager = google.newManager();
}

static abstract class Company {
    public Manager newManager() {
        return new ManagerBuilder("Eve", "Page").age(40).build();
    }
}

static class Google extends Company {
}
```

You can easily add new companies and change the way a manager (or any other employee) is created, you can also use the default.

### Refactoring

With some more playing around, you can remove the boiler plate code in the classes for employees and their corresponding builders, by creating two base classes as follows

```
static abstract class Person<P extends Person<P>> {
    protected final String firstName;
    protected final String lastName;
    protected final int age;

    public <T extends AbstractBuilder<P, T>> Person(AbstractBuilder<P, T> builder) {
        this.firstName = builder.firstName;
        this.lastName = builder.lastName;
        this.age = builder.age;
    }
}

static abstract class AbstractBuilder<P extends Person, T extends AbstractBuilder<P, T>> {
    protected final String firstName;
    protected final String lastName;
    protected int age;

    public AbstractBuilder(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    abstract T self();

    abstract P build();

    T age(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        return self();
    }
}
```

Utilizing the above, creating a class `Manager` and its `Builder` yields following code

```
static class Manager extends Person<Manager> {
    public <T extends AbstractBuilder<Manager, T>> Manager(AbstractBuilder<Manager, T> builder) {
        super(builder);
    }
}

static class ManagerBuilder extends AbstractBuilder<Manager, ManagerBuilder> {
    public ManagerBuilder(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
    }

    @Override
    ManagerBuilder self() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    Manager build() {
        return new Manager(this);
    }
}
```

`Manager`and its `Builder`, or any other employee can be extended with more fields.

Comment: Thanks the detailed writeup, I learnt some important practices here. To be clear, DevBuilder in my code was a static nested class, not a static method. You started your answer on a note that static nested classes don't offer an extensible design - yet you followed the same in your answer. What am I misunderstanding ?

Comment: If you wrote `new Google.Developer.DevBuilder("John", "Doe").age(30).build()` **then** `DevBuilder` would be a nested class. Without the **new** it's just a static method. My use of static nested classes comes, because I put all the classes in one file, but that was just to create a fast example. If classes are nested and you don't use the **static** keyword, you bind the classes to an object of the class they are nested in.

Comment: `Google.Developer.DevBuilder` can also be interpreted as a non-static method call of  the method `DevBuilder` on the instance `Developer`, which is an **enum** of type `Google`. Which doesn't make the approach better, since you have to recompile, if you want to add any companies.